# IntelliJにTomcat設定の際、ポート1099エラー

Tags: macos, tomcat, intellij-idea

こんにちは。

早速質問ですが、Macで「IntelliJ、バージョン15」にウェブサーバ（Tomcat 8.0)
設定の際、1099ポートが使えません。

コンソールに出力されるメッセージは下記のようです。

> ”Application Server was not connected before run configuration
>   stop,reason:　 Unable to ping server at localhost:1099”

ちなみにStack Overflowから少し調べ、試したのが下記のようです。

①/etc/hostsでホスト名を設定。
②自分のMacでホスト名を設定する。

追記します。
etc/hosts
127.0.0.1      localhost

マックに設定されているホスト名 : localhost
JAVAはバージョン８です。

上記処理を行った後、ウェブサーバーを再起動してみましたが結果はダメでした。

宜しくお願いします。

Comment: tomcat8はJava7で動かしていますか？

Comment: /etc/hosts の内容を質問に追記できますか？

Answer (score 1):

自分で解決した履歴です。

IntelliJのjava設定にて、システムのJVMとして
ロードされるように変更して解決しました。

IDE全体的な設定とproject設定を両方変更。

(既存設定はIntelliJ基本のJVMでした。
おそらく、JVMのpath問題だったと思います。)